# Swiper.js not rendering component when used as a slide

Tags: javascript, html, angular, swiper.js

I'm adding [virtual slides](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#virtual-slides) to my swiper with swiper.js. The array that contains the slides, according to the examples, use strings like below (docs say slides: any, but I tried a component and other things, but nothing else worked):

```js
virtual: {
  // cache: true,
  slides: (function() {
    const slides = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 1; i += 1) {
      slides.push('<img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=1/>';
    }
    return slides;
  })()
},
```

**Problem** - I want to use a custom component 'app-member-card' as my slide instead of a string, so I add it as a string like below, but when it's rendered on the screen it doesn't interpolate/transpile/compile/render/etc the components code or HTML, the debugger shows the string I passed it.

I'd like to do this:

> slides.push('<app-member-card class="router-link" [MemberCard]="member"></app-member-card>');

Where this below is what I'd see on the screen:

```html
<div class="card member-card">
  <div class="row">...other tags left out here for verbosity</div>
</div>
```

**Question**: Is there something I can do in Angular or swiper.js that will translate this string into the component when adding it as a slide? I couldn't find anything in the swiper doc and not that familiar with all of the Angular stuff.

**What I tried** - I tried dynamically creating the component in my .ts file and adding the properties, but when I try and extract the innerHTML as a string from the viewContainerRef all data is empty. [Here is my link to that post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72539670/1186050)

Answer (score 0):

You're overdoing it. There's a reason for it to be "that hard" in Angular to inject HTML in it.

The [answer I gave you at the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72581350/1657465) should be enough to fulfill your desired result. However, the best approach would be to NOT store HTML. Instead, store what is needed for `app-member-card` to be rendered.

Something similar to this:

```
export interface IMemberCard{
    id: number;
    url: string;
    wSize: number;
    hSize: number;
}

...

virtual: {
  // cache: true,
  slides: (function() {
    const slides: Array<IMemberCard> = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 1; i += 1) {
      slides.push({
        id: i + 1;
        url: 'https://picsum.photos',
        wSize: 600,
        hSize: 600
      });
    }
    return slides;
  })()
},
```

Then in your HTML you can render `app-member-card` directly:

```html
<div class="row" *ngFor="let slide of slides">
    <app-member-card class="router-link" [MemberCard]="slide"></app-member-card>
</div>
```

That's just how Angular is meant to be used, the hacky-thing I posted in the other question is ok to be used as long as you don't care about maintainability. Generic/dynamic code can get messy really quick.